# Google Api v3 get modified event via watch(web_hook)

Tags: php, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api, webhooks

Am using Google Api v3 for adding and modifying google events .
most of the thing works fine except am unable to get the changes made in google events
am using the below code :

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Analytics.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php';

$client_id = 'my-client_id';  // works without this
$Email_address = 'my-Email_address';
$key_file_location = 'my-key_file_location.p12';


$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("app-name"); // works without random names
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);

$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly');


$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($Email_address, $scopes , $key);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired())
{
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}


$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$cals = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();

$event->setSummary('04/03 appointment -1');
$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2015-03-27T11:00:00.000-00:00');
$start->setTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2015-03-27T11:25:00.000-00:00');
$end->setTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta');
$event->setEnd($end);
$attendee1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
$attendee1->setEmail('myemail@gmail.com'); 
$attendees = array($attendee1);
$event->attendees = $attendees;
$recurringEvent = $service->events->insert('randome-id@group.calendar.google.com', $event);
echo $dynamicId =  $recurringEvent->getId();

$events = $service->events->listEvents('randome-id@group.calendar.google.com');

echo "<br>start - into web hoot <br>";

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$channel =  new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($client);
$channel->setId($dynamicId);
$channel->setType('web_hook');

echo '<br>';
echo $url = 'https://mydomain.com.return.php';
$channel->setAddress($url);

$timetoExpire = time()+3600000;


$optParams = array('ttl' => $timetoExpire);
$channel->setParams($optParams);

try
{
    echo "<br>";
    $watchEvent = $service->events->watch('randome-id@group.calendar.google.com', $channel);
    print_r($watchEvent);
    echo "<br>hook applied<br>";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e;
    echo "web hook not working<br />.";
}

echo "<br>end";

exit;
```

return response comes properly in https://mydomain.com.return.php but still am not sure how to read the response

and am unsure 
what is

```
[resourceId] =7U94nhlXTXH_tK13-5JIrZTBWU0
[resourceUri] =https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/randome-id@group.calendar.google.com/events?alt=json
```

please help me to figure out how to get the modified event date in goggle calender Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your HTTPS addresses has valid SSL certificate installed on your web server ?? other wise Google calendar API will not be able to send notificaitons. Also, is your watch request successful for your notification channel?

Comment: yes it has . and it works fine as well  Thanks SGC

Comment: When i modify something 
google responds back to return.php page i.e : mydomain.com/return.php
when i try print_r in return.php to a text file its showing nothing.
am not sure how to get the modified event data

Comment: the below document its has mentioned as do a incremental sync
http://googledevelopers.blogspot.in/2013/07/google-calendar-api-push-notifications.html 
unsure how to do in php
changes = service.events().list("my_calendar@my-host.com")
  .setUpdatedMin(lastSynchonizationTime).execute();